# Expression implicitly coerced from 'Int?' to Any, even after explicitly defined

Tags: swift

I am getting this error in a Dictionary even I have explicitly defined as [String: Any?].

[image]

Comment: it's a warning not error , besides what do you expect when you set values of different types and make the dic value type `Any?`

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to suppress this warning add "as Any" to the following of each value in your dictionary.

```
let dictAddress: [String: Any?] = [ { "id" : self.id.value as Any } ]
```

Comment: This will silence the warning but why i need to cast to Any, when I have already defined as Any?.

Comment: The Any type in swift is treated as an actual strong type, not a keyword to just accept all types. Therefor you actually have to cast types to Any, even though they could always be interpreted as Any.

Comment: The swift compiler here realizes that these values should be type casted to Any, and does it for you with only a warning. This is fine because there is only 1 swift compiler, Xcode, but if this were a different language with multiple compilers the lack of explicit type casting would leave the interpretation of this code open to the compiler, and you could have different results in different environments.